# How to open a new window in Tkinter if my login username and password are correct in my login window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want to open a new window once my **username and password** are correct in my first login window, my login window file is named **main.py** and i have defined a function to validate my **username and password**

```
for i in c:
    if user == i['USUARIO'] and contra == i['CONTRASEÑA']:
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Correcto', message='Usuario y Contraseña Correctos')
        menuPrincipal.destroy()
        mainformuser.open()
        break
else:
    messagebox.showerror(tittle=None, message='Usuario o Contraseña Incorrectos')
```

it works fine until **menuPrincipal.destroy()** which is my first window, i used **destroy()** to close it once the **username and password** are correct, the problem is when I want to open a new window, my second window file is named **mainformuser.py** and in that file I've defined a function **def open():** and imported to the first file. it works(though give me this error

> invalid command name "2716849470592time" , while executing
> "2716849470592time"
> ("after" script))

but I think I should use **def open():** in my new window because I need to do many things in my second window and all that should be included in **def open():**, What's the right way to insert my windows once i push the login button and my username and password are right??, any idea please let me know, thanks

**UPDATE**

This is my second window file **mainfomuser.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox

 
def open():

    top = Tk()
    top.title('Menú Principal')
    top.configure(background='black')
    top.resizable(True, True)
           
    app_width = 1300
    app_height = 777
    screen_width = top.winfo_screenwidth()
    scree_height = top.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (screen_width/2) - (app_width/2)
    y = (scree_height/2.2) - (app_height/2)
    top.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')
```

Comment: Have you used `<widget>.after(...)` anywhere in your code?

Comment: It is not an error, its just a warning indicating to function `time`? Check [here](https://github.com/nihaalnz/patient-hsptl-app/blob/1697e0ae19ad6d372b8030f2408ebd35aabc6c76/Patient_Information.py#L120) to see something similar I did but instead I put everything inside a single file.

Comment: @TheLizzard    I haven't used any `<widget>.after(...)` , though It is working fine, my main problem is to include my new window into the condition to validate my **username and password** i mean once my **username and password** are right then **destroy()** (close login window) and open my new window.

Comment: @CoolCloud     Hey man is it right how am i including my new window `mainformuser.open()` inside my login funtion `def login():` ? ** I'll do many stuff in the new windows so I don't know if all it should be included in `def open():`

Comment: We cant see the `mainformuser` you are talking about, so its hard to say.

Comment: @CoolCloud I've updated the file `mainformuser.py` it has `def open():` which I'm using in the first window(login file) `mainformuser.open()`

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @CoolCloud I want open my second window `mainformuser.py` from my first window, as I've shown in my first window file i have `def login():` to enter my password and username so I want to include to that function once my password and username are right then open `mainformuser.py`

Comment: Why is `mainformuser.open()` not working?

Comment: @CoolCloud it's working, but I will do manythings in that new window `mainformuser.py` something like other functions, other frames inside that windows and labels and buttons, so I'm not sure if i do all that inside `def open():` it will be fine?, isnt other way to call `mainformuser.py` ? What I' want to avoid is that there might be issues defining new functions inside my `log open():` , for example inside `log open():` can i define other funciton like `def button1():`?? I dont know if you understand me .

Comment: Yes you can define more functions inside one function. And calling the function from other module is also a clean solution.

Comment: @CoolCloud OH that's great, so all i want to do in my second window will be under my `def open():` thanks buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always nice to keep your code clean by keeping everything inside a separate module and importing it. But there is a thing, or two, to note with `tkinter`.

- Whenever you say `Tk()` you are creating an instance of a Tcl interpreter. So now throughout the code, this interpreter will be used, unless mentioned to use a new one. So if you import the new file, make sure to say destroy the old `Tk()` before making one more `Tk()`.
- But here I think its better here to use `Toplevel()` for your new window instead of `Tk()` and instead of `menuPrincipal.destroy()` say `menuPrincipal().withdraw()` to hide the main window and later `menuPrincipal.deiconify()` to bring it back up whenever you please to do so.

I don't know much about your code, so if you don't intend to reuse the window you are destroying, then you can proceed with destroying it instead of hiding it.

Comment: Do you have idea how to connect 2 entries with a sqlite database? my two entries are for 'entry' and 'exit' and i have one button which should be working for both entries, `c.execute('SELECT * FROM superusuario WHERE idcard = ? ', cardin, cardsal)` **superusuario is my table in my database** and i have one column **idcard** , cardin and cardsal are the values for my entries, i tried this `if c.fetchall(): messagebox.showinfo(.....) else: messagebox.showerror(...)` it works only if both entries are filled, i want it works only if one of them are right

Comment: @Paul Why are you using 2 entry boxes but only 1 column inside `WHERE` clause?